# Angular ui-router does not work for firefox os packaged apps

Tags: firefox-os

I am trying to make the basic ionic-tabs app to work on my firefoxOS device. The app is bundled correctly by ionic and I can upload it to my phone, but when I click on anything on the sidebar it displays an error message, that says that "A network error occured while trying to reach the site". It's weird since this is a packaged app, so everything is local, but somehow the angular-ui router does not work for firefox os. I tried to change the csp in the manifest.webapp, but could not resolve the problem.

Any idea?

Comment: Here is a Firefox OS app that uses angular js routes: https://marketplace.firefox.com/app/firedict The source code of the routeProvider: https://github.com/tuxor1337/firedict/blob/master/js/app.js I don't know anything about ionic, but maybe this post was still helpful ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can find the answer here :

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/Apps/Build/App_development_FAQ#Why_am_I_getting_an_.22address_wasn't_understood.22_error_or_broken_images_with_AngularJS.3F

> When you use Angular data binding to generate a URL, Angular will match the URL against its whitelist. If the URL does not match, Angular prefixes the url with "unsafe:" (see the Angular documentation). To make you app work with AngularJS, you can add "app:/"--the protocol FirefoxOS packaged apps use--to Angular's whitelist. In your app's configuration, this is how to whitelist "app:/":

Simply add this code to your app.js (or any file where you initialise your angular application) and it should work fine :

```js
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])
.config(["$compileProvider", function ($compileProvider) {
    $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(file|https?|ftp|mailto|app):/);
}])
```